# Have different listeners in different ways on same event

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, actionevent

I'm having a bit of an hard time wrapping my head around swing and an event-driven interface. I'm working a school project, we have to build something like a chessboard, where we can place pieces and move them and attack each other on input. So here's where I'm getting lost:

I have my chessboard (somewhat) set up. I have a number of tiles (which is a model which holds coordinates and the piece it has on it and a view which is a barebone subclass of JComponent for now) laid out on a JPanel.
Then I have the pawn, which can move, attack, etc...

Now, when I click the tile I have to do different things. For example:

- If the tile is empty, I want to put a pawn on it.
- If the tile is occupied, I want a dialog to popup with different buttons (Move, attack...) on it.
- If I click move, I have to click on another tile and check if it's occupied or not and then change the state of the first tile and the pawn.
- If I click attack I want to click on another tile and change and if it's occupied change the state of the pawn that's on the tile.

Now, the first two are somewhat easy, I can have the pawn listen to the tile and when the tile is clicked I can show the dialogue (if there is a pawn on the tile), or if the tile is free place the pawn on it.

The problem comes when I have to click the button on the dialog and then another tile and have multiple things communicate.

What can I do? 
Say we're talking about the attack button.

1. I click the tile, the pawn listens to the click and shows the dialog.
2. I click the attack button, the listener of the attack button receives the input.

Now what?

I think I should have to have the "attack button listener" listen the tiles too. But it should only react in that way under specific circumstances. How do I have the listener do nothing when I click a tile and I don't want to attack?
I don't think I can just look at the event object (because I can't directly modify it in order to do what I need right?). So maybe the best thing would be to give the listener a reference to my "game system" object, which controls the game basically (turns, available pawn, time, etc), and have a variable there which is used to differentiate the kind of state the game is in (move, attack, place pawn...).

Little tangential question, is it good or bad practice to give listeners and things like buttons references to their surroundings (like the frame they're in or in this case the game system). From my beginner's point of view, if a button or a listener doesn't have references to what they need to interrogate/access in order to work they can't do anything basically, but maybe I'm wrong and I'm doing it the wrong way.

I hope I exposed my problem in a clear way. Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: You look to be way over-complicating things. Why have a dialog? Why not either highlight the clicked square with a piece, and then let the user make a second click and move the click. Then the model (the non-gui representation of your game) checks to see if the move is valid and if it's an attack and what not. All the main logic should go into your model, and the GUI itself should be as dumb as possible.

Comment: I thought about the dialog because I wanted a popup to appear when the user clicks a tile with a pawn so that it can choose what to do. 
You say "move the click", what do you mean exactly? If I remove the dialogue I remove a layer of complexity sure, but don't I still have the problem of clicking the first tile, then the second one and react to the second click in a different way?
And yes the main logic is already in my model/controller, basically what I don't understand really well is how to "gather the data" to feed the logic.

Comment: A click is just a click, and to the GUI, the "view", it means nothing other than "the user clicked on this square". This information is then reported to the model, and its subsequent behavior will depend on its current state. So the model should know if this is a first or second click and then act accordingly. But your GUI listeners will likely be very simple, and mainly act in reporting the events to the model, and that's it.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. This will be of help for sure.